# Let p be an odd prime. Then $\sum a^{-1} ≡ 0\mod p$ where $a$ from $1$ to $p-1$, and $a^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove:

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} a^{-1} ≡ 0\pmod p$ where $a^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $p.$

I think it is a true statement.

$\sum a^{-1} =(1^{-1} +2^{-1} +....+(p-1)^{-1} =[(p-1)(p)]/2 ≡ 0 \mod p$

so $[(p-1)(p)]/2 ≡ 0 \mod p$

$[(p-1)(p)]/2=np$

so $n=(p-1)/2$

I am not sure am I in right way ? any help with that thank you

Comment: Click on Help , click on Help Center, click on How Do I Format Mathematics Here? etc

Comment: I edited you question to make the $\LaTeX$ render properly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path.

You need to argue that $\sum a^{-1} = \sum a$ because the map $a \mapsto a^{-1}$ is a bijection.

Then you can finish as you have done:
$$
\sum a^{-1} = \sum a = \frac{(p-1)p}{2} = \frac{(p-1)}{2}p \equiv 0 \bmod p
$$
Note where you need $p$ to be odd.

Comment: Could you please explain it more , I do not understand the hint , thank you very much

Comment: how about ≡ 0(mod p)?

Comment: can I start like since p is odd prime then $\sum a^{-1} = \sum a$ ≡ 0(mod p) and then (p-1)p/2 ≡ 0(mod p) , is this like complete proof

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{1,..., p-1\}.$ For any finite non-empty set $T$ of numbers let $\sum T$ be the sum of the members of $T.$ The function $f:S\to S$ where $xf(x)\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is a bijection so $\{f(x):x\in S\}=S$ so $$\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=\sum \{f(x):x\in S\}=\sum S= \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}j.$$

So you are right.

Comment: how about ≡ 0(mod p)?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.